# How to handle new replica in RDS Cluster with Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, scalability, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We are prepping for a very large surge of traffic, but the question is also meant as a generic one:

Knowing that you can set up Sequelize to use a cluster of RDS Databases (in our case: Aurora) like so:

```js
const master = { rdsClusterWriterEndpoint, username, password, port, database }
const replica = { rdsClusterReaderEndpoint, username, password, port, database }
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  pool: {
    handleDisconnects: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    idle: 10000,
  },
  replication: {
    write: master,
    read: [replica],
  },
})
```

How could I handle adding a new RDS instance to the cluster to load balance reads even more without reloading the app?

I've pocked around but couldn't find a good way to do it.
The DNS resolution seems to be done once at startup time and I haven't found a way to refresh it every once in a while.

Has someone found a safe way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with a configuration like this:

```js
const getRandomWithinRange = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min)
  max = Math.floor(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min // The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
const maxConnectionAge = moment.duration(10, 'minutes').asSeconds()
const pool =     {
  handleDisconnects: true,
  min: pool.min || 1, // Keep one connection open
  max: pool.max || 10, // Max 10 connections
  idle: pool.idle || 9000, // 9 secondes
  validate: (obj) => {
    // Recycle connexions periodically
    if (!obj.recycleWhen) {
      // Setup expiry on new connexions and return the connexion as valid
      obj.recycleWhen = moment().add(getRandomWithinRange(maxConnectionAge, maxConnectionAge * 2), 'seconds')
      return true
    }
    // Recycle the connexion if it has expired
    return moment().diff(obj.recycleWhen, 'seconds') < 0
  }
}
const master = { rdsClusterWriterEndpoint, username, password, port, database, pool }
const replica = { rdsClusterReaderEndpoint, username, password, port, database, pool }
const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  replication: {
    write: master,
    read: [replica]
  }
}
```

The connection within the pool are recycled at regular interval which triggers spreading to new replicas introduced in the cluster.

It's not ideal as most of the time it is recycled for no reason and when you add replicas to handle a growing pressure on the DB you may want it to take effect sooner than later, but that's my poor man solution for the moment and it helped us go through a fairly large surge in traffic recently.

For simplicity here I'm using the same pool configuration for master and readers but obviously it shouldn't be.

If someone has a better idea, I'm all ears ;)

Comment: Did you find anything better than this?

Comment: @fedtuck we introduced some random to connexion recycle to prevent all connections from recycling at the same time but no, we didn't investigate much more, it's worked for us sufficiently well that we never needed a better solution.
We have a specific configuration for both read & write to manage connections. If you find a better way, I'm still interested!

Comment: I didn't find any other good solution so far. Testing the one you posted with AWS and Aurora (Postgres), it is creating new connections after the time out, but not removing the previous, so it is crashing after a few hours of running.

Comment: ```pool: {
  handleDisconnects: true,
  min: pool.min || 1,
  max: pool.max || 10,
  idle: pool.idle || 9000,
  validate: (obj) => {
    // Recycle connexions periodically
    if (!obj.recycleWhen) {
      // Setup expiry on new connexions and return the connexion as valid
      obj.recycleWhen = moment().add(getRandomWithinRange(maxConnectionAge, maxConnectionAge * 2), 'seconds')
      return true
    }
    // Recycle the connexion if it has expired
    return moment().diff(obj.recycleWhen, 'seconds') < 0
  }
}
```
Hope this helps @fedtuck

Comment: I've edited the answer above with the code including the random part